# Path expected for join hql hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I know this question exists in SO. However I have read many posts looking for this error and I can't solve my problem.

I try to execute an inner join for "many to many" relationships which the middle table has to underline like promotion_code_product, but I write on `@Query` something like this and failed, the error is something like `Path expected for join hql hibernate`

here is my query :

```
 @Query("SELECT p.serviceName, p.category, v.code from Product p " 
    + " INNER JOIN PromotionCodeCategory cp ON p.id = cp.productId " 
    + " INNER JOIN Voucher v on v.id = cp.promotionCodeId " 
    + " WHERE v.code = ?1")
```

i also tried something like this :

```
@Query("SELECT p.serviceName, p.category, v.code from Product p INNER JOIN PromotionCodeProduct cp ON p.id = cp.productId INNER JOIN Voucher v on v.id = cp.promotionCodeId WHERE v.code = ?1")
```

entity like this :

```
@Table(name = "VOUCHER")
@DynamicUpdate
//@Data
@Setter
@Getter
public class Voucher extends Base {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "PROMOTION_CODE_PRODUCT",
               joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "PROMOTION_CODE_ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID"))
    private Set<Product> products;

    @Column(name = "CODE", unique = true)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "TYPE", nullable = false)
    private String type;

    @Lob
    private String descriptions;

    public int hasCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
//@Data
@Setter
@Getter
@DynamicUpdate
public class Product extends Base {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Voucher> promotionCodes;

    @Column(name = "SERVICE_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String serviceName;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORY")
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    public int hasCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that hql joins are not the same as regular sql joins.

With hql you perform queries on entities instead of tables.

So joins are performed for fields contained within an entity.

Assuming your product class contains a List or Set of PromotionCodeCategory called "categories" and your PromotionCodeCategory contains a List or Set of Voucher called "vouchers", then your query should look like this:

```
@Query("SELECT p.serviceName, p.category, v.code from Product p " 
    + " INNER JOIN p.categories AS cp " 
    + " INNER JOIN cp.vouchers as v " 
    + " WHERE v.code = xxx")
```

---

## Edit

It's been noted that there are only two entities: Product and Voucher. Hence your classes should look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product { 
  
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "product_voucher",   // insert join table name here
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") }, // insert product column name from join table here 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "voucher_id") } // // insert voucher column name from join table here
    )
    Set<Voucher> vouchers = new HashSet<>();
    
    // standard constructor/getters/setters
}

    
@Entity
@Table(name = "vouchers")
public class Voucher {    
  
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "vouchers")
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
     
    // standard constructors/getters/setters   
}
```

Then the join query should look like this:

```
@Query("SELECT p.serviceName, p.category, v.code from Product p " 
    + " INNER JOIN p.vouchers AS v " 
    + " WHERE v.code = xxx")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have 3 table ,, one for voucher and one for product , and the another one is for join table like Voucher_product : product_id , and Voucher_id

Comment: I know. If you're using hibernate then you must also have Product , PromotionCodeCategory and Voucher classes with Hibernate mappings. Moreover your Product class must have a PromotionCodeCategory or a Set<PromotionCodeCategory> field and your PromotionCodeCategory class should have a Voucher or Set<Voucher> field in order to perform inner joins using hibernate and hql

Comment: Could you add The Product, PromotionCodeCategory and Voucher classes as well as the error's full stack?

Comment: can u like my entity I just write ?

Comment: that is only 2 entity for manyToMany, only that, onlty Product and Voucher classes, and then create JoinTable

Comment: then that's the problem. you need Product , PromotionCodeCategory and Voucher classes with Hibernate mappings and with fields referencing each other in order to perform an inner join like the one you're trying

Comment: did u mean, i should create another class ?? like domain for PromotionCodeCategory?

Comment: Yes. You must have a Product, PromotionCodeCategory and Voucher classes with hibernate mappings in order to perform such a join

Comment: The kind of join you're trying to do suggests that a Product holds many PromotionCodeCategories and PromotionCodeCategory holds many Vouchers. Is that right?

Comment: if i write that class, it mean, i create another table in Database . right ?, i was type, it was should be PromotionCodeProduct, because it is from table relation Product anbd Voucher called promotion_code_product, u can see on join table product or voucher classes, how to put promotion_code_product then for joining ? because promotion_code_product  containe product_id and promotion_code_id

Comment: Wait... i think I misinterpret your problem. You only have 2 entities: Product and Voucher and you have a join table that holds Product and Voucher ids right?

Comment: yes you are right, the product_code_product table is a conjugation of those 2 tables, so, how to inner join for those ?

Comment: check my updated answer. Product will hold the @ManyToMany configuration. Within the annotation you must specify the name of the join table for product and voucher. If this helps, please upvote and mark it as correct answer

Comment: I think your query is work, but I get result like this ```[Ljava.lang.Object```

Comment: That's because you're selecting some product fields with `SELECT p.serviceName, p.category, v.code from Product p`.

If instead you want to select products (and all of its fields) then change the query to `FROM Product p INNER JOIN p.categories AS cp INNER JOIN cp.vouchers as v WHERE v.code = xxx"` (remove the SELECT statement)

Comment: hold on, can u change your answer so i can understand about this